# In Xcode how do I change what Executable that the app bundle starts up?

Tags: xcode, executable, bundle, targets

I have an app bundle that boots off of a executable called "program" in the .app/Contents/MacOS.  I built a new executable that I placed in .app/Contents/MacOS called "bootstrap".  I have "bootstrap" copied into the app bundle, how do I make my app bundle start executing on "bootstrap" instead of "program".

Thanks in advance